# SyntaxError in PagesController#home unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost

On localhost, after launching rails server. Trying to build a simple navbar with options for social sign-ins. When I try to add "Sign in with Google" and "Sign in with Facebook" I get the following error:

**"SyntaxError in PagesController#home
/Users/okazemi/Desktop/testapp/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:40: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input"**

```
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
```

**With the "<%= render 'layouts/header' %>" being highlighted in red.**

Here is the application.html.rb code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TestApp</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

The code for the _header.html.erb that is referenced in the render is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 <%= link_to "testapp", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %><li>
    <li><%= link_to "Recruiter", recruiter_path %><li> 
    <li><%= link_to "Employer", employer_path %><li> 
    <li><%= link_to "Postings", postings_path %><li> 
    <li><%= link_to "testing", testing_path %><li> 
    <li><%= link_to "Learn", learn_path %><li> 

    <% if user_signed_in? %> Signed in as <%= current_user.name %>. Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
    <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %> 
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Any help would be greatly suggested. Have spent hours trying to figure out if I'm missing an end somewhere but nothing seems to be sticking out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems in the `_header.html.erb`, the most important one out of those is that you have an extra `<% end %>` in the code which is causing the syntax error. I have marked it with `<!-- Remove this extra end -->` comment in the below code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<!-- ....... -->

  <% if user_signed_in? %> Signed in as <%= current_user.name %>. Not you?
  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %> 
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
  <% end %>

<% end %> <!-- Remove this extra end -->
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

A few suggestions:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "testapp", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- Close list item tags with </li> and NOT <li> -->
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Recruiter", recruiter_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Employer", employer_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Postings", postings_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "testing", testing_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Learn", learn_path %></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Below code is not used as list items so remove it from the unordered list element (<ul>)--> 
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Signed in as
        <%= current_user.name %>. Not you?
        <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>
        or
        <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
        <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
        <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div> <!-- Add this closing tag -->
</nav> <!-- Add this closing tag -->
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it. Thanks so much!